# Screen scraping when results can't be found?

Tags: nokogiri, mechanize, null, screen-scraping

I have the following code in a screen scraping rake task

```
page = agent.get("https://domainname.co.uk/unit/27/logs?type=incoming&page=8")
page = agent.page.search("table tbody tr").each do |row|
  next if (!row.at('td'))
  time, source, destination, duration = row.search('td')[1..5].map{ |td| td.text.strip }
  parsed_time = Time.parse(time)
  unless Call.find_by_time(parsed_time)
    Call.create({:time => parsed_time, :source => source, :destination => destination, :duration => duration})
  end
end
```

This section of the script navigates to page 8 and then creates a call record for each table row of data.

If the page I have navigated to doesn't contain any calls logs, it show the following code:

```
<tr class='no-data'>
 <td colspan='7'>There are no call records matching the search criteria</td>
</tr>
```

When the rake task navigates to a page with no call logs the tasks fails to complete. It shows the following error:

```
rake aborted!
can't convert nil into String
```

So, is there a way when using Nokogiri and Mechanize to recover from nil? Is there a simple way of checking if `<tr class='no-data'>` exists before trying to import the data?

**Update with suggested code**

Error message

```
Scraping Page 9
rake aborted!
can't convert nil into String
```

Code

```
puts 'Scraping Page 9'    
    if agent.page.root.css('tr.no-data').empty?
      page = agent.get("https://domaindname.co.uk/27/logs?type=incoming&page=9")
      page = agent.page.search("table tbody tr").each do |row|
        next if (!row.at('td'))
        time, source, destination, duration = row.search('td')[1..5].map{ |td| td.text.strip }
        parsed_time = Time.parse(time)
        unless Call.find_by_time(parsed_time)
          Call.create({:time => parsed_time, :source => source, :destination => destination, :duration => duration})
        end
      end
    else
      puts 'No calls on this page'
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to see if that element exists

```
if agent.page.root.css('tr.no-data').empty?
   # it doesn't exist
else
   # do the normal thing
end
```

Comment: Never mind! I was putting the if statement before the page URL. Thanks!